# Whois lookup response gives error when calling its properties method

Tags: whois-ruby

**Using this gem:** whois (3.6.5)

**Doing this:**

`Whois::Client.new(timeout: 2).lookup('miaz.ca')`

And then trying to call `.properties` on the result of the call (pasted below)

> ```
> "Domain name:           miaz.ca\nDomain status:         registered\nCreation date:         2014/03/12\nExpiry date:
> ```
>
> 2018/03/12\nUpdated date:          2017/03/02\nDNSSEC:
>   Unsigned\n\nRegistrar:\n    Name:              Go Daddy Domains
>   Canada, Inc\n    Number:            2316042\n\nName servers:\n
>   ns61.domaincontrol.com\n    ns62.domaincontrol.com\n\n% WHOIS look-up
>   made at 2017-08-15 20:13:15 (GMT)\n%\n% Use of CIRA's WHOIS service is
>   governed by the Terms of Use in its Legal\n% Notice, available at
>   http://www.cira.ca/legal-notice/?lang=en \n%\n% (c) 2017 Canadian
>   Internet Registration Authority, (http://www.cira.ca/) \n"

But then calling `Whois::Client.new(timeout: 2).lookup('childrenandco.qa')`
gives *this* response and `.properties` gives a `undefined method 'zip' for "shops.myshopify.com":String`:

> ```
> "Domain Name:                     childrenandco.qa\r\nLast Modified:                   15-Aug-2017 14:06:49 UTC\r\nRegistrar
> ```
>
> Name:                  W3INFOTECH W.L.L\r\nStatus:
>   inactive\r\n\r\nRegistrant Contact ID:           W3R2736\r\nRegistrant
>   Contact Name:         Ibrahim  alobaidan\r\nRegistrant Contact Email: 
>   Visit www.domains.qa\r\n\r\nTech Contact ID:
>   W3T2736\r\nTech Contact Name:               Ibrahim  alobaidan\r\nTech
>   Contact Email:              Visit www.domains.qa\r\n\r\nName Server:
>   shops.myshopify.com\r\n"

Comment: Please post the entire code. It's not clear what the value you posted is (which kind of object), nor the code you are using. Also provide the exact version of the client and the parser.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Ah, sorry, too many assumptions on my part. Updated!